# Passing a callable to the default option of a model field fails

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a model named Package. It has fields named, diagnosis, treatment, patient_type, mf and tp. The fields diagnosis, treatment and patient_type have foreign keys defined in separate individual classes, making diagnosis, treatment and patient_type choice fields. Now, what I intend to achieve is that whenever the user chooses the treatment and patient_type from the choices, I want certain figure to appear in mf as a default value. It should be dependant on both the above fields. I have defined a function that takes treatment and patient_type as its arguments, applies the suitable conditions and returns the relevant figure. But when I assign the function to the default option to the mf field, run the migrations and open the webpage and fill in the details in treatment and patient_type, the mf does not return the desired value. What is going on here, is there something that I am doing wrongly?

**The models**:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    diagnosis=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diagnosis

class Treatment(models.Model):
    treatment=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.treatment

class PatientType(models.Model):
    patient_type=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient_type


class Package(models.Model):
    rt_number=ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=max_fraction(treatment, patient_type))
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**The function that is added to the default option in the mf field**:

```
def max_fraction(tt, ptt):
    
    if tt=='YEO5' and ptt=='RUHPE':
        return 40
    if tt=='D4EG' and ptt=='KILEU':
        return 40
    if tt=='5GED' and ptt=='IMRA':
        return 40
```

**The forms**:

```
class DiagnosisForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Diagnosis
        fields='__all__'

class TreatmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Treatment
        fields='__all__'

class PatientTypeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PatientType
        fields='__all__'

class PackageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Package
        fields='__all__'
```

**The views.py**:

```
def package_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_package=PackageForm(request.POST)
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(request.POST)
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(request.POST)
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(request.POST)
        if fm_package.is_valid() and fm_diagnosis.is_valid() and fm_treatment.is_valid() and fm_patient_type.is_valid():
            diagnosis=fm_diagnosis.save()
            treatment=fm_treatment.save()
            patient_type=fm_patient_type.save()
            package=fm_package.save(False)
            package.diagnosis=diagnosis
            package.treatment=treatment
            package.patient_type=patient_type
            package.save()
            fm_package=PackageForm()
            fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm()
            fm_treatment=TreatmentForm()
            fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm()
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form2':fm_diagnosis, 'form3':fm_treatment, 'form4':fm_patient_type, 'form5':fm_package})
    else:
        fm_package=PackageForm()
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm()
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm()
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm()
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form2':fm_diagnosis, 'form3':fm_treatment, 'form4':fm_patient_type, 'form5':fm_package})
```

**The template**:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form2.as_p}}
        {{form3.as_p}}
        {{form4.as_p}}
        {{form5.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**The URLs**:

```
path('package/', views.package_view),
```

Please, help me out here.

Comment: You can not work with other callables in the default function. A `default=...` is a callable *without* parameters.

Comment: ohh! So is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: override the `save` method, etc. But that is circumvented when a bulk create is done. I would make the field nullable, and add a property such that if it is `NULL`, you calcuate the default.

Comment: You mean, like a validator or something?

Comment: no, if the field is `NULL` you let the property return the result of the function call, if it is not `None`, it will return the value of the underlying field.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. Let me try it. :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually what happened now is that when I create these methods after setting the default=None and null=True, and run migrations, it removes the max_fractions field from the model itself. What could be the reason?

Comment: because the field is renamed from `max_fractions` to `_max_fractions`. It is the property on top of it that thus is used to fetch.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, it did get added and shows up in the form. But there is another issue, now, when I select the data in treatment and patient_type fields, the _max_fractions field does not get prepopulated. And when I click on submit, the field raises the validation error 'This field is required'! Is there something wrong with my max_fraction() function?

Comment: noob87: the form will never populate, since Django is the backend: it renders a page. Since the other fields are thus unknown to Django, it can not change the page it has provided. In that case, you will need JavaScript to interactively do this.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. You've been a big help today, learned something useful from you. Will try doing it with JS. :)

Comment: Dear, @WillemVanOnsem, I have asked another question related to this problem which contains a JS problem. If you could answer that, that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237114/trying-to-auto-populate-a-model-field-using-javascript-and-it-does-not-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default=…` can work with a callable, but that callable does *not* have any parameters.

What might be a more elegant solution is make the field NULL-able and then define a property that will in case of a `None` determine the value, so something like:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    # …
    _max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    # …
    
    @property
    def max_fractions(self):
        if self._max_fractions is None:
            return max_fraction(self.treatment, self.patient_type)
        return self._max_fractions

    @max_fractions.setter
    def _set_max_fractions(self, value):
        self._max_fractions = value
```