# Trying to auto-populate a model field using JavaScript and it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a model named `Package`. It has fields named, `diagnosis`, `treatment`, `patient_type`, `max_fractions` and `total_package`. The fields `diagnosis`, `treatment` and `patient_type` have foreign keys defined in separate individual classes, making `diagnosis`, `treatment` and `patient_type` choice fields. Now what I want is to auto-populate the `max_fractions` and `total_package` fields whenever `treatment` and `patient_type` are selected. I was suggested to use JavaScript to accomplish that. I tried and wrote the codes but to no avail. I'm trying it on `max_fractions` field first, when I succeed in doing that, I will do it for all the needed fields.

Can anyone help me on this, it will be much appreciated.

Here are my models:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    diagnosis=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diagnosis

class Treatment(models.Model):
    treatment=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.treatment

class PatientType(models.Model):
    patient_type=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient_type


class Package(models.Model):
    rt_number=ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class DiagnosisForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Diagnosis
        fields='__all__'

class TreatmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Treatment
        fields='__all__'

class PatientTypeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PatientType
        fields='__all__'

class PackageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Package
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
           "treatment" : forms.Select(attrs={"onmouseup":"mf();"}),
           "patient_type" : forms.Select(attrs={"onmouseup":"mf();"}),
        }
```

**views.py**:

```
def package_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_package=PackageForm(request.POST)
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(request.POST)
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(request.POST)
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(request.POST)
        if fm_package.is_valid() and fm_diagnosis.is_valid() and fm_treatment.is_valid() and fm_patient_type.is_valid():
            diagnosis=fm_diagnosis.save()
            treatment=fm_treatment.save()
            patient_type=fm_patient_type.save()
            package=fm_package.save(False)
            package.diagnosis=diagnosis
            package.treatment=treatment
            package.patient_type=patient_type
            package.save()
            fm_package=PackageForm()
            fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm()
            fm_treatment=TreatmentForm()
            fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm()
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form2':fm_diagnosis, 'form3':fm_treatment, 'form4':fm_patient_type, 'form5':fm_package})
    else:
        fm_package=PackageForm()
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm()
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm()
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm()
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form2':fm_diagnosis, 'form3':fm_treatment, 'form4':fm_patient_type, 'form5':fm_package})
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function mf(){
    tt=document.getElementById("id_treatment").value;
    ptt=document.getElementById("id_patient_type").value;
    if (tt=="YEO5" && ptt=="RUHPE")
    document.getElementById("id_max_fractions").value=40;
    else if (tt=="D4EG" && ptt=="KILEU")
    document.getElementById("id_max_fractions").value=40;
    else if (tt=="5GED" && ptt=="IMRA")
    document.getElementById("id_max_fractions").value=40;
}
```

**the template**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="{% static 'account/js/myjs.js' %}"></script>
    <title>Package Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form2.as_p}}
        {{form3.as_p}}
        {{form4.as_p}}
        {{form5.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**URLs**:

```
path('package/', views.package_view),
```

**EDIT**:

I just noticed in the source page of my template that as the `treatment` and `patient_type` fields are dropdown fields, it has `select` and `option` tags. In the `option` tags, the values contain autoincremented numbers (as it is a foreign key bound field) and not the equivalent values that I entered as text. What are my options here?

```
<p><label for="id_package_form-treatment">Treatment:</label> <select name="package_form-treatment" required id="id_package_form-treatment">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">YEO5</option>

  <option value="2">2DRT</option>

  <option value="3">D4EG</option>

  <option value="4">5GED</option>

  <option value="5"></option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_package_form-patient_type">Patient type:</label> <select name="package_form-patient_type" required id="id_package_form-patient_type">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">RUHPE</option>

  <option value="2">KILEU</option>

  <option value="3">IMRA</option>

  <option value="5"></option>

</select></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple forms in your template, these forms have similarly named fields. Which effectively means you have *duplicate* ids (and even `name` attributes) in your template, causing you to get incorrect values. To solve this you should [add a prefix to your forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms):

```
def package_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_package=PackageForm(request.POST, prefix='package_form')
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(request.POST, prefix='diagnosis_form')
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(request.POST, prefix='treatment_form')
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(request.POST, prefix='patient_form')
        ...
    else:
        fm_package=PackageForm(prefix='package_form')
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(prefix='diagnosis_form')
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(prefix='treatment_form')
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(prefix='patient_form')
        ...
```

This will cause your ids to be of the form `id_<prefix>-<field_name>`, so you would need to change your JavaScript too:

```
function mf(){
    tt=document.getElementById("id_treatment_form-treatment").value;
    ptt=document.getElementById("id_patient_form-patient_type").value;
    if (tt=="YEO5" && ptt=="RUHPE")
    document.getElementById("id_package_form-max_fractions").value=40;
    else if (tt=="D4EG" && ptt=="KILEU")
    document.getElementById("id_package_form-max_fractions").value=40;
    else if (tt=="5GED" && ptt=="IMRA")
    document.getElementById("id_package_form-max_fractions").value=40;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was caught up with something else. I just saw your answer. And thank you for pointing this out. But it still doesn't work. The field doesn't auto populate. Do I need to change the event or something?